# How can I deploy a Vue.js and Nuxt project into Netlify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I have cloned a repository to my local machine and pushed it to my GitHub account. Now, I want to deploy this app to Netlify but when I do that, I get a bunch of errors.
◉ Here is the error I get when I deploy the app to Netlify:
[image: the error I get when I deploy the app to Netlify]

◉ Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/Ibadet02/wedance_platform

Comment: What if you change your `build` command in your `package.json` to "nuxt build"?

Comment: It did not work. I still get the same error

Comment: The error you have here is related from a REST api response (maybe some backend service is not properly configured/responding). Your repo have quite a complex setup with Docker, Firebase, Services etc... Also, since you're using your Nuxt app as SSG (`target: 'static'`), hence why you should be running `yarn generate` and not `build`.

Comment: Since I don't know the backend. Can you help me to track the error here and make the app run on Netlify? It is so important for me.

Comment: Netlify is made only for static apps. It can't really run a backend. So, you may not be able to deploy your whole github repo on it if it has a backend (with a required server) needed. Still, try `yarn generate` and check if it works locally.